# HTML5 video doesn't play in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video

So I have a website, which I just use for fun, but I currently have a problem with the website ([uppah.net](http://www.uppah.net))

I'm simply trying to play a video on the website, but it doesn't show up on Chrome. It works fine on Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer.

I've read that Google Chrome doesn't support MP4, so I tried to change the video formats into WebM, but with the same result.

I'm using the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        <title>Uppah</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="FCNTiGM.gif" rel="shortcut icon" />

        <script>
            function load() {
                document.getElementById("vsrc").src = Math.floor((Math.random()*11)+1)+".mp4";
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body onload="load()">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <video autoplay class="video" loop><source id="vsrc" /> Please update your browser.</video>
        </div>


        <div id="polina">
            <h1>Uppah</h1>

            <p><a href="http://steamcommunity.com/id/Uppahmost" target="_blank">Steam Profile</a></p>
            &nbsp;

            <p>You won&#39;t find any hacks here, noob. :^)&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've tried to change:

```
<script>
    function load() {
        document.getElementById("vsrc").src = Math.floor((Math.random()*11)+1)+".mp4";
    }
</script>
```

Into

```
<script>
    function load() {
        document.getElementById("vsrc").src = Math.floor((Math.random()*11)+1)+".webm";
    }
</script>
```

But it doesn't play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you append to the wrapper div the whole video element like this

```js
function load() {
  var src = Math.floor((Math.random()*11)+1)+".mp4";
  var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
  wrapper.innerHTML = '<video autoplay class="video" id="video" loop><source src="'+src+'" type="video/mp4" /> Please update your browser.</video>';
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <title>Uppah</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="FCNTiGM.gif" rel="shortcut icon" />

  </head>
  <body onload="load()">
    <div id="wrapper">

    </div>
    <div id="polina">
      <h1>Uppah</h1>

      <p><a href="http://steamcommunity.com/id/Uppahmost" target="_blank">Steam Profile</a></p>
      &nbsp;

      <p>You won&#39;t find any hacks here, noob. :^)&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is a working example (just hit "Run with JS" button in the output section): http://jsbin.com/kabibifoqo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Runs perfectly! Thanks a lot!